# Open Cover of $0 < |x| \leq 1$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I have to give an example of the following:

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2} \ |\  0 < |x| \leq 1\}$. Give an open cover of $A$ that has no finite subcover of $A$.

Furthermore, I have to prove this is true, but I cannot think of an example. I know an example of such a problem for the interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot think of one for this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tell us the example you know for $(0,1)$.

Comment: What is the example that you know for the interval $(0,1)$? Probably you can modify it using balls to obtain one for $A$, which is simply the unit disk without the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your example in one dimension looks like the one below but with $\mathbb{R}^2$ replaced by $\mathbb{R}$.

For $j \in \mathbb{N}$ define

$$
A_j= \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{1}{n} < \vert x \vert < 2 \}.
$$

Then $(A_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open cover of $A$ without a finite subcover. The proof is similar to the one-dimensional case.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$ is a cover of $(0,1]$ by open intervals that has no finite sub cover. Consider the centers $c_n=\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{2}$ and the radius $r_n=\dfrac{b_n-a_n}{2}$ of these intervals.

Notice that $A$ is precisely the unit disk without the point $(0,0)$. Now, for every $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, consider the open disks $D_{n,\theta}=B\left((c_n\cdot \cos \theta,c_n\cdot \sin \theta);r_n\right)$ centered at $(c_n\cdot \cos \theta,c_n\cdot \sin \theta)$ and radius $r_n$.

Using polar coordinates, every element $(x,y)\in A$ can be written uniquely as $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and $0<r\leq 1$. So, if $r\in I_n$ (when consider in the interval $(0,1]$), then $(x,y)\in D_{n,\theta}$.

Also, if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ ($r=0,\theta=0$) belongs to some $D_{n,\theta}$, then $|0-c_n|<r_n$, which implies that $0\in I_n$, contradicting the fact that none $I_n$ contained $0$.

Comment: I was thinking it was a problem about metric spaces, hence I used balls. If the problem is about topological spaces, certainly NiU's answers works easier.